# Is return variable automatically created by compiler?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

When going over the project source code, I stumbled upon a method and wondered about one thing. Are the following two methods EXACTLY same from the performance/memory/compiler point of view?

```
public static string Foo(string inputVar)
{
    string bar = DoSomething(inputVar);
    return bar;
}

public static string Foo(string inputVar)
{
    return DoSomething(inputVar);
}
```

Is the return variable automatically created by compiler?

Comment: If *that* is an actual performance bottleneck for you, congratulations. However, my experience suggests it's unlikely to be. Write the code that you find to be clearest, worry about performance when performance issues are actually proven and you determine where best to invest your resources.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: This is not a question about performance. Just a simple question on how .Net/C# works.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - so the mention of performance in the question and the question being *tagged* performance should be ignored?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is a question about both performance and how C# works. When creating the question, I assumed it is clear enough that the type of `bar` is specified as string as an example. It might as well be a complex type that needs lots of memory. Congratulations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using *IL Disassembler* (included in the .NET SDK/VS) you can look at the IL generated by the compiler. The code is generated using VS2013 (not Roslyn).

The top one gives the following IL:

```
.method public hidebysig static string  Foo(string inputVar) cil managed
{
  // Code size       14 (0xe)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string bar,
           [1] string CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  call       string TestIL.Program::DoSomething(string)
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldloc.0
  IL_0009:  stloc.1
  IL_000a:  br.s       IL_000c
  IL_000c:  ldloc.1
  IL_000d:  ret
} // end of method Program::Foo
```

The second one:

```
.method public hidebysig static string  Foo(string inputVar) cil managed
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  call       string TestIL.Program::DoSomething(string)
  IL_0007:  stloc.0
  IL_0008:  br.s       IL_000a
  IL_000a:  ldloc.0
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method Program::Foo
```

The difference seems to be that the first one creates an extra entry in the methods locals table. If this is optimized away by the JIT compiler I don't know.

To answer the question: No, it doesn't seems that the compiler automatically generates a local variable in this case, but in more advanced case it might do (like return x * (y + z)).

Edit: If you turn on "Optimize code" its even more clear:

```
.method public hidebysig static string  Foo(string inputVar) cil managed
{
  // Code size       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string bar)
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       string TestIL.Program::DoSomething(string)
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  ret
} // end of method Program::Foo

.method public hidebysig static string  Foo(string inputVar) cil managed
{
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       string TestIL.Program::DoSomething(string)
  IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method Program::Foo
```

Comment: Consider turning on compiler optimations. I expect it will trim down the IL to 3 respectively 5 instructions and will make the difference more obvious.

Comment: That residual `stloc`/`ldloc` pair looks, on the face of it, to be trivially optimisable. Any clues as to why the optimiser didn't do that? Or, come to think of it, what effect the `.maxstack 8` has?

Comment: This is just a guess: Its because most of the optimization is deferred to runtime, when the JIT compiler is doing the real optimization. In order for the JIT compiler to make the best decisions, the compiler skips some optimizations so the JIT compiler has better understanding of the program.

Comment: So there is a difference from compiler point of view. In that regard, the second method is better as far as I understood.

Comment: Technically compiler needs to add a return local only in cases where it needs to do a return from a place not allowing ret - like return from a try block. In such case return value would need to be spilled in to a temp before jumpling to an exit label where the value from the temp can be returned.        
Generally the return local is unnecessary and optimized codegen will try avoiding it. Not too hard though - one extra local is not a big deal.

Comment: @ClickRick  stlock/ldlock  is indeed redundant and Roslyn will optimize it when compiling with /o+. Note that as a result you will not be able to stop "}" and examine "bar", when debugging optimized code. .maxstack 8  is just because the method uses trivial "tiny" header which means "no locals, no exception frames, maxstack <= 8".